# boost.thread - access violation in a simple example

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, visual-studio-2015, boost-thread

I'm just trying to run a very simple example of using threads with `boost`. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void workerFunc()
{
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);
    workerThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get an exception:

```
(boost_thread-vc140-mt-1_59.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000019.
```

Despite the exception, the program works and I can see `hi` in console. I use VS2015, x64 configuration. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Works great. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/995c7ff324c92c12

Comment: On a side note, why do you need boost::thread in 2015?

Comment: I use it to create a cross-platform code.

Comment: Try running the debug build in the debugger.

Comment: @SergeyA maybe he doesn't. That's a strange comment.

Answer (score 2):

There's clearly undefined behaviour, as there's nothing wrong with the code.

So, what ***is*** wrong?

There's likely an error in the build configuration, deployment (runtime environment), or a mismatch between those two.

Specifically:

- you might build your project with a compiler version/flags that make it binary incompatible with the libraries used.
- you might link to the import libraries of 1 build/version of boost and be finding a different version at runtime

Both conditions introduce [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen.